# Populate version of s3 file dynamically on Github Actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, github-actions, circleci

I am trying to migrate from circle CI to GitHub actions and I am stuck at this step where I am trying to populate the version of a s3 file dynamically.

This is how it is being done on circle CI and it works fine

```
echo "export FILE_LOCATION='s3://xxx-xxx/'${PROJECT_NAME}_$(cat VERSION)'.zip'" >> $BASH_ENV
```

This is how I tried doing it on Github Actions config

```
env:
  NAME: '${{ github.repository }}_$(cat VERSION).zip'
```

However, I get the following error when I run it on GitHub actions

```
cat: VERSION: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to handle such values to be dynamic on GitHub actions? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an environment variable, add it to the file behind `$GITHUB_ENV` like so:

```yaml
- run: echo "NAME=${{ github.repository }}_$(cat VERSION).zip" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- run: echo ${{ env. NAME }}
```

For more information, see the docs on [Workflow commands for GitHub Actions / Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)

Comment: Any idea how to create the version itself dynamically? This version is for naming the war files after the maven build is complete

Comment: Please create a new question and accept this one if it solves this particular problem.